# Adding multiple variable types in for_each in terraform?

Tags: azure, foreach, terraform, azure-web-app-service, conditional-operator

I want to add multiple ip addresses to configure access restrictions in azure for an app service and also this should be accomplished only for a few environments, I'm using the dynamic block to achieve this, it was working as long as there was only one IP, but now I want to allow more ip addresses, is there a way to achieve this?

```
dynamic "ip_restriction" {
  for_each = var.ip_addresses
   content {
     ip_address = ip_restriction.value["ip_address"]
     priority   = ip_restriction.value["priority"]
     name       = ip_restriction.value["name"]
   }
 }
```

This works perfect but I want to add the environment restriction as well. something like

```
for_each = var.env == "dev" || var.env == "qa" ? [1] : []
```

Comment: That sounds like exactly what dynamic blocks are for. Instead of asking "is there a way", edit your question to show your code and explain what isn't working, including any error messages, so we can help you with the actual issue you are encountering.

Comment: Some code will be nice

Comment: These post can help you, [dynamic ip restriction for app services on azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69265869/dynamic-ip-restriction-for-app-services-on-azure-using-terraform)

Comment: Hi @MarkB, I've added the code and changed the frame of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This works perfect but I want to add the environment restriction as
> well.

You are really close, you just need to change this array: `[1]` to be the actual array of IP addresses, like so:

```
for_each = var.env == "dev" || var.env == "qa" ? var.ip_addresses : []
```